# Ubuntu does not boot once after switching from Windows 8 with dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I seem to have a weird issue with dual-booing Ubuntu and Windows 8 (UEFI mode). Whenever I use Windows 8, restart the machine and then boot Ubuntu (13.04) with grub boot-loader, Ubuntu freezes during the boot. I do not get to the login screen. However if I power off my machine after this occurs and power it on again Ubuntu boots just fine. Any suggestions on why this might be occurring and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hardware initialization problem -- Windows has left some hardware device in a state that Linux doesn't like, resulting in a hang. You might be able to learn more by removing the `quiet` and `splash` kernel options (by editing your boot options in GRUB). This will result in verbose startup messages, which may provide a clue about what hardware device is the source of the problem. With that information in hand, perhaps you could research it better and find a fix.

Failing that, I suggest you try hitting your computer's reset button (if it has one) during the reboot process. That might reset the hardware adequately, but I can make no promises. Another option might be to drop to a GRUB command line and issue a `reboot` command before booting Linux. It's conceivable, but unlikely, that GRUB's reboot operation would do a better job of resetting the hardware than Windows' reboot operation.